# watch not update change vue

Tags: vue.js, redux

i'm try to change variable by watch and change it in to html

```
<p>{{customer.creditsLeft}}</p>
```

and vue

```
data() {
   customer: {},
 }
 watch: {
 '$store.state.jobs.listBooking.customer': function (newVal) {
  this.customer.creditsLeft = newVal;
  console.log('current credit now' + this.customer.creditsLeft);
  return this.customer.creditsLeft;
 }
},
```

console.log is woking but creditsLeft still not change. i'm a new bie in vue . pls help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add new property to customer object you need to use set, otherwise it's not reactive.

```
this.$set(this.customer, 'creditsLeft', newVal)
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Or you can set it before hand so you don't need to use set

```
data() {
   customer: {
      creditsLeft: 0
   },
}
```